# implementing custom view style in actionbar

Tags: android

I want to implement this kind of functionality in android, 
for example, when i click on Pinterest the **arrow sign** will be automatically moved to piterest (Like  you can see in image) now if i press twitter then arrow will be moved to there like that..., arrow will move with animation, if anybody knows how to implement then please let me know

[image]

Like in above image there is three button (Facebook, Pinterest, Twitter), you can see piterest is selected so arrow is below the pinterest now if i press facebook the arrow will move below facebook image with animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to make three different images.

**1st**:

[image]

**2nd**:

[image]

**3rd**:

[image]

So you do,

```
if(images[1] was clicked){
imageView.setdrawable(image1);
} else if(images[2] was clicked){
imageView.setdrawable(image2);
} else if(images[3] was clicked){
imageView.setdrawable(image3);
}
```

Comment: Is there any inbuilt Library for that??..otherwise i will change image

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can search gitbuh or any other similar sites. Good luck.